# Does the reputation of a company matter in stock trading?

Tags: stock-markets

One person who I worked for in trading stocks stated that the reputation of a company never matters when looking at the rise and fall of its stock prices. After working with them for some time, that's what the data seemed to suggest. Regardless of if a company announced success or failure at any point or any news stories that may have related to their business, the prices fluctuated without indicating a correlation to that PR.

On the other hand, I clearly remember seeing that BP's stock prices plummeted after their gulf oil spill.

So how do you know when reputation will have any bearing on the stock prices of a company?

Comment: I bought BP shortly after their gulf debacle. Profited quite nicely!

Comment: With debacles like the BP's Deepwater Horizon spill, there's no way to know where the bottom is.  Props to you for buying it and grabbing that short term profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word reputation has a very broad definition and therefore, your question doesn't have an easy answer. And even with attempt at definition, there are no easy metrics available for measuring how such components translate into dollar value.  But let's name a few...

On the consumer level, it's meaningful in terms of

- quality of products and services (consumer is satisfied with one product so he buys other products made by the company)
- the company provides community & environmental responsibility 
  .

On the corporate level, you can measure or compare different metrics like :

- the finances of the company
- the ability of management
- domestic or global competitiveness
- innovation

I'd say that most of these apply to investing and that your friend is correct.  Trading is a function of the most recent news coupled with a top down correlation the market/sector (a rising tide carries all boats).  It's a bet that a short term trend will continue and in such a small slice of time, a company's reputation is meaningless.

Regarding your mention of BP, that wasn't a reputation issue.  That was a catastrophe destined to seriously affect profitability due to clean up fees, fines and penalties.  And though subsequent investigation showed that BP (as well as Transocean and Halliburton)   was careless, the stock price collapse was event  driven rather than reputation driven.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how relevant reputation is for the financial prospects of the company.

Comcast is the most hated company in America, but it makes a profit and its stock is doing quite well. Folks may hate Comcast, but if they want an Internet connection they'll pay them.

On the other hand, the accounting company Arthur Anderson was destroyed by its conviction for a felony in the Enron scandal in 2002 (the conviction was later overturned, but the company was long gone by then). The difference between Comcast and Arthur Anderson is that the long term value of an accounting company depends critically on its reputation for probity and honesty. Although its short term prospects may depend on its willingness to be "accommodating" to its clients, an accounting company that is widely and publicly known to wink at deceptive practices and even help in disguising fraud has no value. Its certifications that proper accounting rules have been followed will be worthless.

Answer (score -2):

No.

With trading, you focus on short term (!) changes in price.

The reputation of a company will only matter when it CHANGES - otherwise it is a constant within the time period. If the company sucked yesterday and still sucks end of the week, sucking as a company will not influence the price within the week.

OTOH if it was great beginning of the week and now it is nearly broke - obviously the price will tank. But not because it nearly broke but because of the change in reputation.

Generally: only unexpected (!) changes are relevant to a price.

> On the other hand, I clearly remember seeing that BP's stock prices plummeted 
>   after their gulf oil spill.

Which was not related to the reputation. Well, ok - you can argue their reputation took a hit with the spill (i.e. CHANGE in reputation), but seriously, that ALSO - and primarily - was a pretty big financial mess they will have to pay, so the stock price obviously goes down due to damage that suddenly appears in the company books.

Comment: "The reputation of a company only matters when it changes..." Yes I believe that was implied by the question, so now I don't actually know if anything you said is applicable. I'm talking specifically about when the reputation changes as a result of their success/failure or news.

Comment: Success/Failure RARELY happens in timeframes that matter to trading. New "happens", particularly if it is a sudden catastrophy.